# Hilbert $C^*$ modules

Tags: hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. I want to view $H$ as a Hilbert $C^*$ module over $\mathcal{B}(H)$. First let me take $H=\ell^2$. Identify $x \in \ell^2$ as $1 \times \infty$ matrix $(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$. Regard $H$ as $B(H)$  module by matrix multiplication. Define the $B(H)$ valued innerproduct on $H$ by $\langle x,y\rangle =(\overline{x_i}y_j)$. I want to prove that the Hilbert $C^*$ norm on $H$ is nothing but the usual $\ell^2$ norm. I am not able to do that.

By definition, the Hilbert $C^*$ norm is $\|x\|=\sqrt{\|\langle x,x\rangle\|}$. By the above definition, $\langle x,x\rangle $ is the matrix $(\overline{x_i}x_j)$. I want to find its operator norm. Or Am I making any mistake?

Comment: Check that $\langle x,y\rangle (z) = \langle \overline y , z\rangle_H \cdot \overline{x}$ where $\overline y$ is $y$ with all components complex conjugated (so maybe you actually want $\langle x, y\rangle = (x_i\overline y_j)_{ij}$). Do you see how to continue?

Comment: Thank you .. I could prove it.

Comment: In general, how a Hilbert space $H$ is a Hilbert $K(H)-$ or $B(H)-$module? I know how I can define the inner product, but how can we define the multiplication operation?

Comment: @Darman both $K(H)$ and $B(H)$ act (from the left) on $H$ as operators.